# Angular 8 : how to convert hh:mm to minutes?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am new to angular.I am using ngx-timepicker in that i am getting date as 2019-10-14T02:15:00.949Z in this i have to get hours and convert it into minutes(for my request).How to achieve this.

My code:

html file:

```
<timepicker [(ngModel)] ="timeentryData.workedhours" (input)="timeentryData.workedhours=parseDate($event.target.value)" ngDefaultControl [showMeridian]="isMeridian" [showSpinners]="showSpinners" class="mr-auto mb-0"></timepicker>
```

in ts file i am using @input to pass post request,

```
@Input() timeentryData = { taskId: '', userId: '5d9fd84d3d598088d2ea5e0d', teamId: 'Applications Developement', roleId:'Developer', clientId:["Sciera"], workedhours: '',status: 'Accepted', description: '', workFrom: 'office'};

parseDate(dateString: any): Date {
      console.log('Parsed date'+dateString);
      if (dateString) {
        var d = this.timeentryData.workedhours;
        var date1 = new Date(d);
        var hours = date1.getHours() * 60; // To convert hours into minutes
        this.hours_minutes = date1.getHours() * 60 + date1.getMinutes(); // To sum the hours and minutes into minutes
        console.log('Actual Date->'+date1);
        console.log('*******');
        console.log('Hours->'+hours);
        console.log('*******');
        console.log('hours_minutes->'+this.hours_minutes);
        console.log('*******');
        console.log(this.convertMinsToHrsMins(this.hours_minutes));
        return this.hours_minutes;
      }
      return null; 
   }
```

for that workedhours i need to pass as minutes from the date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
var date1 = new Date('2019-10-14T02:15:00.949Z');
var hours = date1.getHours() * 60; // To convert hours into minutes
var hours_minutes = date1.getHours() * 60 + date1.getMinutes(); // To sum the hours and minutes into minutes
```

Comment: sunny parekh: im getting minutes but in this how to i pass this changed value into @input in ts.I having trouble in that.i need that one

Comment: Kindly change the question title accordingly. It is misleading.

Comment: Why are you using @Input()? you can directly get it from the [(ngModel)] in your .ts file.

Comment: i am forming my post request in @input so ,in ngmodel i am getting only that date. after processing in ts file only i am getting minutes.

Comment: Yeah so that is the ideal flow. @Input() is used to get the data from parent to the child component only.

Comment: so we cant change anything ah (i.e) cant able to change any values after that ah?